# Filter Count All in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I convert this code in the active record:

```
$last_points = mysql_insert_id(); 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(fkmember) FROM downline WHERE fkmember = {$last_points}";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->db->select('COUNT(fkmember)');
$query = $this->db->get_where('downline', array('fkmember'=> $last_points))->num_rows();
```

Comment: i try to run all of your code but none of it is working. Some display 0 and some display error.

Comment: here is my full code in inserting data in downline table                      $insert_downline = array(
                        'down_id' => null,
                        'level' => $this->member,
                        'fkmember' => $id, //referral id
                        'downline' => $last_insert //member id
                        );
                    $downline =  $this->db->insert('downline',$insert_downline);
                    
                   $last_points = mysql_insert_id();

Comment: You need to assign the last insert id to $last_points before using it in the code I gave you. If you are getting unexpected results, perhaps your data isn't consistent.

Comment: it displays nothing/blank why is it happening?. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

First, when using an aggregate function like COUNT, it's recommended to use a GROUP BY

```
$last_points = $this->db->insert_id();

$this->db->from('downline');
$this->db->where('fkmember', $last_points);
$this->db->group_by('fkmember');
echo $this->db->count_all_results();
// Produce an integer, like 17
```

You may also refer to the manual: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$last_points = mysql_insert_id(); 

$count = $this->db->where('fkmember',$last_points)->get('downline')->num_rows();
```

$count gives the count of results

Comment: ok found an answer to my question thanks for the suggestions.